Properties of a range of a composition of two relations
The book "How To Prove It - A Structured Approach 3rd Edition" by Daniel J. Vellman, section 4.2, contains the following exercise:


Suppose $R$ is a relation from $A$ to $B$ and $S$ is a relation from $B$ to $C$.

(a) Prove that $\operatorname{Dom}(S \circ R) \subseteq \operatorname{Dom}(R)$.

(b) Prove that if $\operatorname{Ran}(R) \subseteq \operatorname{Dom}(S)$ then $\operatorname{Dom}(S \circ R)=\operatorname{Dom}(R)$.

(c) Formulate and prove similar theorems about $\operatorname{Ran}(S \circ R)$.


Obviously, $\operatorname{Dom}(A)$ - a domain of a relation $A$, $\operatorname{Ran}(A)$ - a range of a relation $A$.
I was able to prove parts $(a)$ and $(b)$ but I have no idea how to formulate part $(c)$. Can you please formulate properties regarding $\operatorname{Ran}(S \circ R)$ so that I can prove them?

Have you thought about the analogy with functions? For $g\circ f(x)$ to be defined, we at least need $f(x)$ to be defined, thus $Dom(g\circ f) \subseteq Dom(f)$ (link back to question (a)). So for question (c), imagine for the range of a composition $g\circ f$, that any output of said function would in particular be an output of $g$... And what happens if $f$'s outputs cover the entire domain of $g$?
